# Как добавить html 5 аудио плеер к музыке?

Tags: html5, аудио

У меня есть пример - проигрывается музыка - http://www.smartjava.org/examples/webaudio/example3.html
Как сюда добавить кнопки аудио плеера с управлением?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете тег `<audio>`, то попробуйте так:

```
<audio id="myaudio" controls="controls">
  <source src="mysong.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/> <!-- Наш файл -->
  Your browser does not support the audio element. <!-- Будет выведено, если браузер не поддерживает тег <audio> -->
</audio>
<div class="controls"> <!-- Наши кнопки управления -->
  <button onclick("togglePlay()") class='play_pause'>Toggle Play</button> <!-- Play / Pause -->
</div>
<script> <!-- Без JS никуда :) -->
  var myaudio = document.getElementById('myaudio'); // Найти аудио
  var playing = false;

  var togglePlay = function(){
    if(playing) // Если играет
      myaudio.pause(); // Останавливаем
    else
      myaudio.play(); // Иначе играем
  }
</script>
```

Это только часть. Вот классный туториал: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=32&id=1654.

**UPD**

Например, есть такой код:

```
<audio>
  <source src="mysong.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
```

К тегу `<audio>` добавляете атрибуты `id="myaudio" controls="controls"`, а после тега, вставляете:

```
<div class="controls"> <!-- Наши кнопки управления -->
  <button onclick("togglePlay()") class='play_pause'>Toggle Play</button> <!-- Play / Pause -->
</div>
<script> <!-- Без JS никуда :) -->
  var myaudio = document.getElementById('myaudio'); // Найти аудио
  var playing = false;

  var togglePlay = function(){
    if(playing) // Если играет
      myaudio.pause(); // Останавливаем
    else
      myaudio.play(); // Иначе играем
  }
</script>
```

И все!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но понимаете, мне нужно интегрировать плеер именно в имеющийся пример....что думаете. Реально?

Comment: Конечно можно, смотрите update.